# SQL "LEFT JOIN" from multiple databases with a variable database name

Tags: sql, database, filter, compare

I'm trying to query an existing SQL server which has a very different structure than I'm used to. This server manages Bill of Materials (BOMs)for a company. For some reason, this is set up so that each project has it's own database. There is a separate database ("project") to hold the basic information for each project.

My goal is to return a list of all projects which meet a condition in the "project" database AND contain a certain component in their BOM.

I can run a simple SELECT command on the "project" database to come up with all projects which meet the first condition. For example, lets say I'm returning (3x) projects which have an int value (87,89,93).

My challenge is that I now need to check the BOM of these (3x) projects to see if they meet my second condition. I essentially need to add a "WHERE" condition to the end of my search that looks like the following.

```
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(item)
    FROM [PROJECT_87].[dbo].[BOM]
    WHERE item like '%ComparePN%') > 0
```

I'm stumped by figuring out how to change the name of the database "PROJECT_87" for each of the returned projects (87,89,93). I know I can use the SET + REPLACE commands to do the actual replacing of the '87' with the other project numbers. I don't know how to go through all 3 results and perform the SET + REPLACE command for each row to evaluate if the row should stick around.

Thoughts?

Comment: I do not know how to do this with SQL only but if you know a scripting language like python or R it can be done by just replacing parts of the query and re-executing. Not sure if that will help

Comment: You can do this with [Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-dynamic-sql/) - if you can provide a full definition of your source data and expected output, I'm sure someone can help you put the exact query together.